# how to hide Touch to return to call

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have an app with below as navigation bar.

[image]

I see a green area if I am on call.

[image]

For Viber, it show below.

[image]

Is there way we can hide/ remove those unwanted stuff?

What I want is even if I get a call from anyone, it should show me as shown in first image (Without return to call).

***Is there any way for doing this? Even private API is fine with me BUT not jailbroken***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a system behavior. None of the iOS APIs offers to alter it.
So to make it short: **You can't.**

You have to test your app to adapt it's layout when this banner shows up.

Comment: No there is no public API to control this. You can't hide it.

Comment: I will wait for more answers *especially if anyone have API* ***else,*** *I will accept this answer*

Comment: Okay :) But I'm afraid that the only solution would be a jailbroken app.